# Creating and filling the parts and subparts of a file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, design-patterns, thymeleaf

I'm working on a spring boot application with thymeleaf and jpa. One of the functionalities is for the user to create parts and subparts and add subparts to existing parts then add all the parts to an existing book stored in the database . Can someone help me?

I've tried with the composite and builder pattern .

I've tried to use recursive methods to add subparts to parts and to other subparts and to show all the parts in the file stored in the database but I kept having errors . I want the application to generate later the book created by the user (with all the parts and subparts well organised has if it was typed in a text editor)